# Most efficient way to stretch an image in Python NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I want a function to take in an image as a numpy array and remap the values to a new range (0, 1) based on a specified maximum and minimum value from the input range.  I've got a working function, but I'm iterating through the array and it takes about 10 seconds to complete.  Is there a more efficient way to perform this task? Maybe some built in numpy function that I'm not aware of?

This is what I've got:

```
import numpy as np

def stretch(image, minimum, maximum):
    dY = image.shape[0]
    dX = image.shape[1]
    r = maximum - minimum
    image = image.flatten()
    for i in range(image.size):
        if image[i] > maximum or image[i] < minimum:
            image[i] = 1. or 0.
        else:
            image[i] = (image[i] - minimum) / r
    return image.reshape(dY, dX)
```

I've also tried a version of the above using numpy.nditer instead of manually iterating with the for loop but that seems to be about four times as slow (~40 seconds).

Is there a more efficient way to do this that I'm overlooking?  The images I'm working with are about 16 MP. (3520, 4656)

Comment: When I try `stretch()`, the array only contains zero and one. Is this right? I thought the remap function is supposed to clip below min and above max and remap in between using a linear function.

Comment: `1. or 0.` always evaluates to `1.`

Comment: @MrT I get `1`s and other elements greater than zero.

Comment: @Alex Your function delivers, what I would have expected to happen. Hence my surprise, when I tested OP's function output.

Comment: @MrT Added explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bug #1

You have a bug in your code.

`image[i] = 1. or 0.` always evaluates to `1.0` because `1.` acts [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/1953800).

Instead that block should look like:

```
if image[i] < minimum:
    image[i] = 0.
elif image[i] > maximum:
    image[i] = 1
else:
    image[i] = (image[i] - minimum) / r
```

### Bug #2

If your original array is of `dtype=int` and you place values into it they will be coerced to `int`s. This means that any `float`s will be rounded down.

```
a = np.array([1])
a[0] = 0.5
a
```

returns

```
array([0])
```

This can be addressed using the vectorized solution below.

### Solution

In general try not to use loops when dealing with NumPy arrays. Using vectorized functions can be much faster and more readable.

```
def stretch(image, minimum, maximum):
    image = (image - minimum) / (maximum - minimum)
    image[image < 0] = 0
    image[image > 1] = 1
    return image
```

An example (updated to `int` which is more realistic for `image` as @MrT points out):

```
a = np.arange(1, 4).reshape(2, 2)
stretch(a, 1, 3)
```

returns

```
array([[0. , 0.5],
       [1. , 1. ]])
```

Comment: This is not the output I get from the OPs function. Hence my question.

Comment: There's the bug in OP's code `image[i] = 1. or 0.`.

Comment: Ah, I see, what the difference is. Your array is a float. Images contain int. The OP function behaves totally different with integers. Idk, what his intended output is.

Comment: Thanks!  This works much better and good advice about vectorized functions.  My images are dtype '>f8' btw